# Is there a way to TRUNCATE TABLE only if it exists?

Tags: cassandra, cql

Is there a way to truncate a table only if it exists?

This works

```
TRUNCATE TABLE my_keyspace.my_table;
```

How can I do this?

```
TRUNCATE TABLE IF EXISTS my_keyspace.my_table;
```

Comment: I don't know cassandra at all but can you not just attempt to truncate it and catch/handle the error if the object doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

The CQL grammar doesn't support this syntax because the act of truncating a table implies that the operator is fully aware that they want to issue a `TRUNCATE` on the basis that they need to get rid of its contents.

In any case, we do not recommend issuing a `TRUNCATE` programatically since it will fail if any of the nodes in the cluster is unavailable or unresponsive. As such, a DBA is required to verify that all nodes are operational before issuing the command. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Erick Answer is best.

Now for testing purposes what you can think about is creating the table if it does not exist and then truncate.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS simpledata (id int PRIMARY KEY, data text);
TRUNCATE TABLE simpledata;
```